# Pandas: How to delete duplicates in rows and do multiple topic matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have the following dataframe `dfstart` where the first column holds different comments containing a variety of different topics. The labels column contains keywords that are associated with the topics.

[image]

Using a second dataframe `matchlist`

[image]

I want to create the final dataframe `dffinal` where for each comment you can see both the labels and the topics that occur in that comment. I also want the labels to only occur once per row.

[image]

I tried eliminating the duplicate labels through a `for loop`

```
for label in matchlist['label']:
    if dfstart[label[n]] == dfstart[label[n-1]]:
        dfstart['label'] == np.nan
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Further, I have manged to merge `dfstart` with `matchlist` to have the first topic displayed in the dataframe. The code I used for that is

`df2 = pd.merge(df, matchlist, on='label1')`

Of course, I could keep renaming the label column in `matchlist` and keep repeating the process, but this would take a long time and would not be efficient because my real dataframe is much larger than this toy example. So I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this.

Here are three toy dataframes:

```
d = {'comment':["comment1","comment2","comment3"], 'label': ["boxing, election, rain", "boxing, boxing", "election, rain, election"]}

dfstart = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

dfstart[['label1','label2', 'label3']] = dfstart.label.str.split(",",expand=True,)

d3 = {'label':["boxing","election","rain"], 'topic': ["sport","politics","weather"]}

matchlist = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)

d2 = {'comment':["comment1","comment2","comment3"],'label': ["boxing, election, rain", "boxing, boxing", "election, rain, election"], 'label1':["boxing", "boxing", "election"], 'label2':["election", np.nan, "rain"], 'label3':["rain", np.nan, np.nan], 'topic1':["sports", "sports", "politics"], 'topic2':["politics", np.nan, "weather"], 'topic3':["weather", np.nan, np.nan]}

dffinal = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extractall` instead of `str.split` so you can obtain all matches in one go, then flatten the results and `map` to your `matchlist`, finally `concat` all together:

```
d = {'comment':["comment1","comment2","comment3"],
     'label': ["boxing, election, rain", "boxing, boxing", "election, rain, election"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

matchlist = pd.DataFrame({'label':["boxing","election","rain"], 'topic':["sport","politics","weather"]})

s = matchlist.set_index("label")["topic"]

found = (df["label"].str.extractall("|".join(f"(?P<label{num}>{i})" for num, i in enumerate(s.index, 1)))
                    .groupby(level=0).first())

print (pd.concat([df, found,
                  found.apply(lambda d: d.map(s))
                  .rename(columns={f"label{i+1}":f"topic{i+1}" for i in range(1, 4)})], axis=1) )

    comment                     label  label1    label2 label3 label1    topic2   topic3
0  comment1    boxing, election, rain  boxing  election   rain  sport  politics  weather
1  comment2            boxing, boxing  boxing       NaN    NaN  sport       NaN      NaN
2  comment3  election, rain, election     NaN  election   rain    NaN  politics  weather
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really useful, especially pointing out that I need to use str.extractall